# How to do a high-jump on springboards?

Tags: super-mario-bros

I have tested and tried to figure out what the secret is to doing a big jump on [Springboards](http://www.mariowiki.com/Springboard) in the original Super Mario Bros, but have been unable to figure out what triggers it. The closest theory I seem to have is that you have to press "B" while in the air and then hit "A" as you are jumping, but sometimes I still only do a small jump?

Can someone tell me what the official way to get a big jump is when using these annoying things?

Comment: Pretty sure you just have to jump the moment the springboard reaches it's peak compression and is about to send you flying.

Comment: Sheesh, okay, no need for a downvote.

Comment: That comment seems like it's directed at my comment, so I feel like I should let you know that I did not downvote anything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why everyone is down-voting this question? Did I ask something wrong?

Comment: My only guess is that the title was too generic and sounded too simple and there are people who judge the question by title, not the actual question. I edited the title to be more descriptive, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to press A when the trampoline is fully compressed, before it sends you in the air. There's nothing else to it, just got to get the timing right.

[Source saying it's all about timing (mariowiki.com):](http://www.mariowiki.com/Springboard#Trampoline)

> With the right timing of pressing the A Button button, the player will have Mario (or Luigi) be able to go high in the air.

Comment: Ah, okay. Now don't take this the wrong way because it's not like I don't believe you (I do), but do you have any verifiable sources or personal experience for that or is that just how you think it works?

Comment: That's how it always worked for me. Unfortunately, I have no way to test it, other than playing the game until I reach an area with a springboard and my Mario skills are quite rusty... I am fairly certain it works the same in Smash as well. I'll see if I can find any other sources, can't promise anything though.

Comment: @Guy I added a source (from mariowiki that *you* linked) saying that you can do the high jump with the right timing.

Comment: Oh wow I'm an idiot I skipped right over that sentence some how when I read that page. Conveniently, the page doesn't elaborate on what that timing is..

So press A when the trampoline is fully compressed. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :P